# Which app is used to detect friends group in fb?

Tags: facebook, spam-prevention

Recently I approved friend request of a spammer by mistake  ,after one hour I checked facebook again , i noticed that he posted spam all the groups where I am present.   My question is is there any API to get friends groups and send join requests automatically , or am I hacked ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook API gives information about the public groups you are in. This method does it -

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<user_id>/groups?access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>
```

It returns the data in following format -

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "version": 1,
         "name": "The Magnet Link",
         "id": "358110224242411",
         "unread": 1,
         "bookmark_order": 999999999
      },
      {
         "version": 1,
         "name": "NIBS-Care For Mental Health",
         "id": "467292153287893",
         "unread": 9,
         "bookmark_order": 999999999
      },
      {
         "version": 1,
         "name": "Movie Lovers Group",
         "id": "110068659059974",
         "unread": 25,
         "bookmark_order": 999999999
      },
      {
         "version": 1,
         "name": "Book Keepers - A place for Book Lovers",
         "id": "208239532582598",
         "unread": 17,
         "bookmark_order": 9
      },
...
```

So, he can just use the API to get info about the groups you are in.

Although, it's not possible to send Join requests using the API.

Comment: Then hemay created scripts to send join request to groups